# Dockerized Python Application is taking 100% CPU on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I have deployed python application on EC2, but python is taking 100% CPU usage.
Below is the code snippet where i think the issue is.

```
@app.route("/refresh", methods=["POST"])
def preprocess():
    start_time = time.time()

    if flask.request.content_type == "application/json":
        input_data = flask.request.data.decode("utf-8")
    else:
        return flask.Response(
        response='{"Error: Request content type error, REQUIRED: application/json "}',
        status=415,
        mimetype="application/json")

    input_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(input_data)

    prepare_obj = Prepare()
    prepare_output = prepare_obj.preparation()

    end_time = time.time()
    return flask.Response(response=resp, status=200, mimetype="application/json")
```

Is the "time" module causing the issue? We have 2 EC2 instance. In one EC2 i am not getting this issue. But in another EC2 instance i am facing.

Comment: unlikely for time, what does input_data have really?

Comment: input_data contains json which is a API request.

Comment: any chance you use `app.run(debug=True)` ?

Comment: app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=port_number). I am using this.

Comment: try to add `time.sleep(0.5)` right after `end_time = time.time()`

Comment: have  you tried running it without the docker if possible? directly from cmd line? You can also limit the container cpu memory.

Comment: Will try this and check

Comment: @skott no i haven't tried. As deploying docker images is the standard maintained in my organization.

Comment: Understood, I mean't for debugging purpose only, as a test run (if possible)